# Is there a clean way of importing modules?

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a project where I have to import a file to my `index.js` file.

Here's a snippet:

```
import './inspector'
import { openSidebar, collapse } from './inspector'
```

I would like to import everything from the `inspector.js` in order to run more logic inside that file and at the same time importing `openSidebar` and `collapse` function inside it. But I noticed that I'm getting an eslint error `no-duplicate-imports` in my editor.

How to resolve this issue? I'm still learning on how importing in javascript fully works. I was thinking that maybe removing one of the imports will still work. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe `import * as inspector from "./inspector"`? Then you can access use `inspector.openSidebar` and `inspector.collapse`

Comment: The top line seems superfluous, no?  What are you attempting to accomplish by importing it without invoking anything?  Just some initialization?  Seems as though that is approaching being an antipattern.  I imagine you could omit the first line and using just the second would be sufficient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of a module's code will run whenever the module is imported, no matter what gets imported - even if nothing is imported. Given the following module:

```
// inspector.js
console.log('running inspector');
export const openSidebar = () => console.log('opening sidebar');
export const collapse = () => console.log('collapsing');
```

The following code would successfully log `running inspector` (in addition to whatever other code existed on the top level of that module):

```
import './inspector';
```

The following line would also log it:

```
import { openSidebar, collapse } from './inspector';
```

So you should be able to use just that version above, which will run the top level code *and* import the required values from the module.